# do I need to store the cursor for a listview at class level?

Tags: android, android-listview

My listview uses a cursor via an adaptor.  Do I need to keep this cursor variable at a class level for any reason as the Listview adaptor stores it anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Actually i don't understand why you want to do this if you want to access records again then just store them after fetching through cursor and then you can access them any where in your project.

If you keep this cursor variable then you again want to traverse the database in order to retrieve or other operations . But i think make cursor for you function level access records(you can store them in Vector or ArrayList) then use that stored records instead of using cursor.

If you want to tore cursor make it of class level and access it in other classes (but remember the function reinitialize cursor must call first before calling cursor in other classes).

Hope this explanation works for you...